# making an executable with pyinstall: trouble with vlc module (linux)

Tags: python, plugins, vlc

I want to make an executable out of a gui youtube audio player I made.
There is a problem with the vlc module. When I just make the executable (on Linux), I can't open the file.
Opening in the terminal gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "ytplayer.py", line 39, in 
> player = instance.media_player_new()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'media_player_new'
> [24084] Failed to execute script 'ytplayer' due to unhandled exception!

in my code I have:

```
from vlc import Instance
```

and

```
vlc_instance = Instance()
player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
```

I found some information on the net about this problem, but no solution yet. This is one post on the internet:

> By specifying a VLC_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable, everything works as expected! It's an exciting workaround:

```
os.environ["VLC_PLUGIN_PATH"] = "/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins"
```

Problem is: I dont know where my vlc plugins are... So I cant test this.
Does anybody have ideas either for other ways to get around this problem, or to find the path of my vlc plugings?

FYI: My script works perfectly when I dont put it through PyInstaller.

link to the website with the info:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4506

Answer (score 0):

For the plugin paths it depends on your OS:

Your problem is **Linux**, it's here (i don't have a Linux machine so cannot test):

see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/267502/how-do-i-install-vlc-extensions

```
/usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/
```

---

**For Windows** it's in the VLC folder where VLC.exe is.
Likely in `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins`

---

**For MacOS** it's in VLC.app (.app is just a way to hide what's inside, it's basically a regular folder from my limited mac experience).

in Finder, look for VLC.app > control click > "show package contents" > and on my machine it's in contents\MacOS\plugins